# pass by reference a mat object OpenCv

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, concurrency

I'm trying get the web camera video feed from a thread(different class).. and i wanted to return the Mat object in to main method... so far i know only to do that is to pass a reference of a Mat object which created in the main method to the thread. 
 but it was not working perfectly, this error appears
(Unhandled exception at 0x00983489 (opencv_core248d.dll) in ConsoleApplication10.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x05671050.).
can any one help me to get through this problem.

the reason is this my development goes to build in based on Moderator design pattern that's why. 
thank you...!!!

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
class Camera
{
public:
    void abc(Mat &img){ //camara method

        Mat image;
        VideoCapture cap(0);
        namedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        namedWindow("win2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

        while(true)
        {
            cap >> image;   
            if(!image.empty())
            {
                img=image.clone();
                imshow("win2", img);
                imshow("window", image);
            }
            waitKey(1);
        }
    }
    void operator()(Mat &img){//thred method of the class
        abc(img); // passing Object TO method
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Mat mImg;//main method Mat
    namedWindow("win3", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    thread t1((Camera()),ref(mImg)); //passing main method Mat to the Tread PASSING BY REFF
    while(true)
    {
        if(!mImg.empty())
            imshow("win3", mImg);// display main method mat Object
        waitKey(1);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `cv::Mat` has reference semantics, so you *could* pass it by value.

Comment: how??  i don't understand how to do it... :(

Comment: @juanchopanza unless the method reallocates the Mat memory ;)

Comment: @gamal : what does thread t1 do with the mat? You will probably need some thread synchronization (mutex for example) so that `if(!mImg.empty())` and `imshow("win3", mImg);` are not interrupted by the other thread manipulating the data of the mat. My guess is, that `t1` will reallocate the memory of `mImg` "during" `imshow` so that imshow will read memory that isnt legal anymore.

Comment: had a look at your function: `img=image.clone();` will reallocate memory, if size of img and image aren't identical. `#include <thread>` will probably give you some mutex classes too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a thread is a good idea to use a camera, but you have to use a mutex to block the image data access. you can find easily documentation and examples.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/

You can also add a boolean to indicate if a new image is available (if your treatment is faster than your acquisition), or use a buffer to stock several images.

Comment: haa haa it worked... thax for all..... :) :) :) :) \m/
for both of the while loops are locked by one local mutex object... nice it works..... (Y)..


while(true)

 {

  mtx.lock();

//code

  mtx.unlock();

 }